# How should I create a responsive canvas with createJs to adapt different mobile device's screens?

Tags: html, canvas, responsive-design, createjs

I want to develop a html5 mobile game. As you know, the screens of mobile devices are different size, so I want to create a responsive canvas so that it can adapt different screen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way is to resize your canvas with JavaScript, based on the viewport, and then reflow the contents.

```
var w = $("#container").width();
var h = $("#container").height();

stage.canvas.width = w;
stage.canvas.height = h;

// Simple "fit-to-screen" scaling
var ratio = contentWidth / contentHeight; // Use the "default" size of the content you have.
var windowRatio = w/h;
var scale = w/contentWidth;
if (windowRatio > ratio) {
    scale = h/contentHeight;
}
content.scaleX = content.scaleY = scale;
```

Here is a simple example. It is a bit different than the sample code to make it work in a resizing window. http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/4yy08pax/

If you are dealing with mobile devices, there are some other things to consider (they auto-scale canvases to account for their high DPI).

Hope this helps.

Comment: What if you have multiple shapes? How can you get the contentWidth / contentHeight of each?

Comment: Do you want to resize every element to fit the screen? Ideally you just have a single piece of content that you scale, and you know the "default" size of that content, which you use in the approach above. The example uses the `exportRoot`, because it has a nominal size it was created at.

Comment: I see what you mean. Imagine your window, or content area is 500 x 300. You stick that into contentWidth / contentHeight - because you only need to calculate the ratio!! Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Lanny Could I not just resize the entire stage instead of having another content layer?

Comment: Resizing stage has some possible side effects. I recommend a sub-container. It has almost no overhead (one additional context transform), and  lets you continue to visualize your stage as a representation of the canvas.

Comment: @Lanny #container in this case is the DOM element that wraps the canvas /stage and then "content" is an actual easeljs Container object that is a child of the stage correct?